# Standard function for inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is there any standard way for inheritance in javascript?
Any standard function which I can use for inheritance, I just pass the two objects(or constructors) and it does the needful.

Comment: I have not seen any "helper" function that deals with inheritance in JavaScript completely because it would be too complicated to write such a function and you still need to do a lot of things yourself. To inherit in JavaScript you need to set child.prototype and call the parent constructor in the child constructor `Parent.apply(this,arguments)` When you want to extend a Parent function you can call a Parent function like so `Parent.prototype.someExtendedMethod.call(this,args);` More information can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: I am not sure but most of the javascript libraries use a fix helper function for inheritance, where they pass the parent and the child as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Node.js, then you can use [`util.inherits`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) funciton, like this

```
util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);
```

Here, `MyStream` is the child and `events.EventEmitter` is the parent.

Otherwise, you can simply use the following code

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Comment: I am using javascript mainly for DOM manipulation in UI.
I think the second one would not work for objects.

Comment: @SushilKumar Can you give an example? The methods I listed are the common ways to inherit.

Comment: Before you start to attempt inheritance with DOM objects, read [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) for the "…downsides of this seemingly useful practice". Working with [*native objects*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) is fine, but [*host objects*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8) are a law unto themselves.

Comment: You are right I think the whole idea of object inheriting from other object is silly.
I wrote the first comment because I thought in javacsript an object(instance) inherits from other object and objects (other than functions) do not have prototype proeprty.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example code generated by [Sharpkit compiler](http://sharpkit.net/) for Inheritance, Hope it helps :)

```
if (typeof($Inherit) == 'undefined') {
    var $Inherit = function(ce, ce2) {
        if (typeof(Object.getOwnPropertyNames) == 'undefined') {
            for (var p in ce2.prototype)
                if (typeof(ce.prototype[p]) == 'undefined' || ce.prototype[p] == Object.prototype[p])
                    ce.prototype[p] = ce2.prototype[p];
            for (var p in ce2)
                if (typeof(ce[p]) == 'undefined')
                    ce[p] = ce2[p];
            ce.$baseCtor = ce2;
        } else {
            var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ce2.prototype);
            for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
                if (typeof(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ce.prototype, props[i])) == 'undefined')
                    Object.defineProperty(ce.prototype, props[i], Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ce2.prototype, props[i]));

            for (var p in ce2)
                if (typeof(ce[p]) == 'undefined')
                    ce[p] = ce2[p];
            ce.$baseCtor = ce2;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit? Which one is child and which one is parent object?

Comment: That doesn't inherit, it combines 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any standard way for inheritance in javascript?

Yes, prototype inheritance. It's [in the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1). The basic pattern:

```
// Constructor
function Foo(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// Constructor's prototype holds properties inherited by instances
Foo.prototype.sayName = function() { return this.name }

// Use new to create an instance
var foo = new Foo('foo');

alert(foo.sayName()); // foo
```

You can also emulate various other types of inheritance, but generally it's not a good idea (or to get to fancy with any kind of inheritance in javascript, it just doesn't need it). Sometimes it helps though.

[Search the interwebs](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=MDN%20prottoype%20inheritance&sourceid=ie9&rls=com.microsoft:en-AU:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=strict&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9hqQU4hPzMLyB-G1gPgF&gws_rd=ssl) or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20inheritance), there are thousands of articles, blogs and answers.

> Any standard function which I can use for inheritance

See *thefourtheye*'s answer and [*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5).